# asp.net 5 / Core Identity Customisation Issues - No Implicit Reference Conversion error

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

So I've been looking at this for several hours now and i'm starting to lose the little hair I have left on it...

I'm testing this on an entirely new website. No worries about dropping tables etc.

I'm using Asp.net 5 / Core with the Identity tools to handle user registration, roles etc.

I want to customise the IdentityUser class to include a few custom fields, like displayname, and description, plus some references to other tables. (E.g. Users will create a Galleries of images, so the gallery table will have a foreign key to the UserId.)

However, following various tutorials online, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I am advised to do the following:

Create a new class for a user with my custom fields, and inherit from the IdentityUser, e.g. UserAccount : IdentityUser.

```
public class UserAccount : IdentityUser
{
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

Update the ApplicationDbContext, to inherit from IdentityDbContext<**NewUserClass**>

[image]

I just keep getting the following error:
Error   CS0311  The type '...UserData.UserAccount' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '....UserData.UserAccount' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'.

What am I missing here?? None of the tutorials seem to have this casting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I feel like an idiot! Posting this here incase anyone else has a similar experience!!!

In your custom class to extend the IdentityUser class, my Visual Studio defaulted to add the reference

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

This is the wrong one! You need to use the following one

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
```

It's obvious now, but I've honestly just spent like 3h trying to get to the bottom of this....

The confusion came in from the NuGet packages you have installed.

I needed the following

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework
```

If you have

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity or
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core or
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core or
```

any of the other similar ones, you will have issues!!

I hope that helps someone!